# float to int conversion oddities in .Net

Tags: string, type-conversion, integer

See this code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    float test = 1.8f;
    Console.WriteLine(test); // 1.8
    
    int intTest = (int)(test * 100);
    Console.WriteLine(intTest); // expected result: 180, but it's 179???
        
    float test2 = test * 100;
    int intTest2 = (int)test2;
    Console.WriteLine(intTest2); // 180 ??
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/R6u4wA

In .Net 4.7 there's a difference in conversion from int to float if you do a calculation in the same line of the conversion vs doing the calculation first, storing it in a float variable and then converting it to an integer.

In .Net 6 this is fine, but I'm using Unity so I cannot change the compiler.

How is this explained and what is the best way to fix this?

Thx for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Try `Convert.ToInt32(test * 100)` instead of `(int)(test * 100)`.

**Note:** Include the System namespace: `using System`

Comment: Both approaches use a cast, but somehow the first cast changes it to 179 and the other does not. It's also not a matter of "rounding" per se; 180 should not be rounded to 179. There should be no rounding whatsoever, 180 is a perfectly fine int value. In .Net 6 this works correctly, so there must be more to this.
You are correct, the Convert works. But it should not be necessary.

Comment: Oh you are totally right, sorry, I didn't see that you casted it in both approaches  I don't know what's going on there, I'm sorry